# How to write a java regex to match anything OTHER than a 3 digit number?

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

It should consider the whole string for comparison. When the whole string is not a three digit number, it should match.

Comment: You mean if the string is "543", no match, and if it is "543a", match? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes. A regex to match anything which is not a three digit number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) you can use the regex

```
^(?!\d{3}$).*$
```

In Java, you would have to escape the `\` with a `\\` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
"\\d{3}"
```

This will get you the three digit number. So everything that is not this regex, is what you're looking for.